# Image property in usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'd like to make a simple UserControl in WPF as follows : an image (let's say 128x128) with another image on it, smaller (48x48). Let's call them imgMain and imgOverlay (the small one).

Now I want to place my UserControl in any WPF app and be able to change the images and their size. I put two properties in my usercontrol and was happy to see them show up in the right form in the VS2010 designer. But when I try to put an image using the designer the control doesn't refresh and stays white. Same if I try to do it at runtime from code.

I read several posts about DependencyProperties and all (something I'm not really familiar with) but they always seem to want to have more logic in the even of an image changing. I want something really simple and only visual.

Here is what I did for the properties :

- the size of the overlay

  ```
  public Size OverlaySize
  {
     get
     {
        return new Size(imgOverlay.Width, imgOverlay.Height);
     }
     set
     {
        imgOverlay.Width = value.Width;
        imgOverlay.Height = value.Height;
     }
  }
  ```
- the Images for main and overlay

  ```
  public Image ImageMain
  {
      get
      {
          return imgMain;
      }
      set
      {
          imgMain = value;
      }
  }

  public Image ImageOverlay
  {
      get
      {
          return imgOverlay;
      }
      set
      {
          imgOverlay = value;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really do have to go and do the whole `DependencyProperty` dance. Sorry about that. WPF introduces its own event system, its own property system and makes you use that. I found it confusing at first. And then just plain tedious. Wait... I'll see if I can dig up some similar code for you...

OK. This little class works as an Image control, that displays a different image depending on the value bound to it...

The xaml code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DesignPerformanceViewer.Controls.BooleanImage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
       <Image Name="image" Height="11" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind with the whole `DependencyProperty` dance...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace DesignPerformanceViewer.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for BooleanImage.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class BooleanImage : UserControl
    {
        private static readonly DependencyProperty TrueSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TrueSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(BooleanImage));
        private static readonly DependencyProperty TrueToolTipProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TrueToolTip", typeof(string), typeof(BooleanImage));
        private static readonly DependencyProperty FalseSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FalseSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(BooleanImage));
        private static readonly DependencyProperty FalseToolTipProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FalseToolTip", typeof(string), typeof(BooleanImage));
        private static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(bool), typeof(BooleanImage),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValuePropertyChanged), new CoerceValueCallback(OnValueCoerceValueCallback)),
            new ValidateValueCallback(OnValueValidateValueCallback));

        public ImageSource TrueSource {  get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(TrueSourceProperty); } 
            set 
            { 
                SetValue(TrueSourceProperty, value);
            } 
        }
        public ImageSource FalseSource { get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(FalseSourceProperty); } set { SetValue(FalseSourceProperty, value); } }
        public string TrueToolTip { get { return (string)GetValue(TrueToolTipProperty); } set { SetValue(TrueToolTipProperty, value); } }
        public string FalseToolTip { get { return (string)GetValue(FalseToolTipProperty); } set { SetValue(FalseToolTipProperty, value); } }
        public bool Value 
        { 
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ValueProperty); } 
            set 
            { 
                SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
            } 
        }

        public BooleanImage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var self = (BooleanImage) d;
            var newValue = (bool) e.NewValue;
            self.image.Source = newValue ? self.TrueSource : self.FalseSource;
            self.ToolTip = newValue ? self.TrueToolTip : self.FalseToolTip;
        }       

        private static object OnValueCoerceValueCallback(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
        {
            if (!(baseValue is bool))
            {
                return false;
            }
            var boolValue = (bool) baseValue;
            var self = (BooleanImage)d;
            self.image.Source = boolValue ? self.TrueSource : self.FalseSource;
            self.ToolTip = boolValue ? self.TrueToolTip : self.FalseToolTip;
            return boolValue;
        }
        private static bool OnValueValidateValueCallback(object value)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much; Indeed it's a little counter-productive compared to the goal I was trying to achieve

Comment: @MickaelV. I don't understand what you mean by "counter-productive": The example? Or the DependencyProperty boilerplate?

Comment: The whole DependencyProperty. I only have 3 images right now and i was thinking doing the usercontrol (in the way I did it) COULD be useful someday. But in the light of these new elements it will be faster to do it manually for my 3 images and maybe try my hand at dependencyproperties later

Comment: @MickaelV., actually, I think that is sound advice: Only generalize stuff when you find yourself doing it again... Not as much fun, because we all like shiny perfect objects, but... it gets the job done and keeps complexity as low as possible: abstractions can be distractions...